# Rolling window with offset different on Pandas DataFrame with PeriodIndex and DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-sum

When creating a pandas DataFrame with a daily PeriodIndex, and doing a rolling window calculation based on an offset (e.g. '5D') the result is not as expected.

I expect the rolling window to be the last 5 days, but instead the window seems to be from the start of the index, and growing for each item.

The rolling works as expected for a DataFrame with a DatetimeIndex

```
df_datetimeindex = pd.DataFrame([0.5]*10, columns=['data'], index=pd.date_range(start='2019', periods=10, freq='D'))
df_periodindex = pd.DataFrame([0.5]*10, columns=['data'], index=pd.period_range(start='2019', periods=10, freq='D'))
display(
    df_datetimeindex.data.rolling('5D', min_periods=1).sum(),
    df_periodindex.data.rolling('5D', min_periods=1).sum()
)

display(df_datetimeindex.index, df_periodindex.index)
display(df_datetimeindex.data.rolling('5D', min_periods=1), df_periodindex.data.rolling('5D', min_periods=1))
```

yields

```
2019-01-01    0.5
2019-01-02    1.0
2019-01-03    1.5
2019-01-04    2.0
2019-01-05    2.5
2019-01-06    2.5
2019-01-07    2.5
2019-01-08    2.5
2019-01-09    2.5
2019-01-10    2.5
Freq: D, Name: data, dtype: float64
2019-01-01    0.5
2019-01-02    1.0
2019-01-03    1.5
2019-01-04    2.0
2019-01-05    2.5
2019-01-06    3.0
2019-01-07    3.5
2019-01-08    4.0
2019-01-09    4.5
2019-01-10    5.0
Freq: D, Name: data, dtype: float64
DatetimeIndex(['2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-04',
               '2019-01-05', '2019-01-06', '2019-01-07', '2019-01-08',
               '2019-01-09', '2019-01-10'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
PeriodIndex(['2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-04',
             '2019-01-05', '2019-01-06', '2019-01-07', '2019-01-08',
             '2019-01-09', '2019-01-10'],
            dtype='period[D]', freq='D')
Rolling [window=432000000000000,min_periods=1,center=False,win_type=freq,axis=0]
Rolling [window=432000000000000,min_periods=1,center=False,win_type=freq,axis=0]
```

Is there an explanation for this behavior that I have missed?

Comment: I assume you know you could do `df_periodindex.data.rolling(5, min_periods=1).sum()` but are just curious about the behaviour. Might be a bug.

Comment: Yes, the PeriodIndex is not necessarily evenly spaced, so in that case i would need to use a time-based offset or reindex before .rolling(). It also works as expected if i convert the PeriodIndex using to_timestamp, but I'm curious if I'm thinking wrong here, or if it is indeed a bug.

Comment: Just noting that this seems to still be in place. Trying to clarify whether it is a bug or if I am missing something

Comment: Maybe create an issue on [their Github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas)?